# Meaning of "for"

Tags: meaning-in-context, for

Can someone please explain the meaning of "for" over here

> Choose how long a banner notification pops up for

Comment: It's used in your example to convey duration. The banner can pop up for a certain duration, perhaps a few seconds or minutes, presumably as governed by the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For" in this example is a hanging prepostition. It completes the phrasal verb started at the beginning of the sentence. The question is "How long for"?(time not distance) with the object placed after long.

Comment: Would the sentence mean the same if 'for' was left out?